# Conversion of an image to a raw bitmap file

Tags: c, image, image-processing, image-conversion

I am trying to run a program which has the following requirement:

> This program reads in an uncompressed gray-scale image with one byte per
>   pixel and a size of 256*256 pixels (no image header)

How do I convert a `jpg` image to fit the above requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With **ImageMagick** at the command-line:

```
magick input.jpg -resize 256x256\! -depth 8 -colorspace gray GRAY:image.raw
```

**ImageMagick** is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. In versions 6 and earlier, change `magick` to `convert` in above  command.

Comment: Don't images with a `.raw` have headers?

Comment: No, they don't. Your file will be 65,536 bytes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format#File_contents According to this it contains a short header?

Comment: That refers to raw formats of photos from certain camera manufacturers. If you mean one of those, you would have to be specific about which one, but I don't believe that is what you mean. Raw also refers to files not encoded as JPEG, PNG, or TIFF which is what you probably want. Just try it! It's easy enough to try.

Comment: That clears things a bit. It confuses me how there are 2 types of `raw` . I was lazy about installing ImageMagick on my system as I thought there must be some online converter that can achieve this for me. Guess I will have to install it after all

Answer (score 0):

Another free tool is IrfanView. It allows to select the needed part, crop it, change size to 256×X, crop again to 256x256, change to grayscale and save it as .raw.

If you need more than conversion (e. g. to choose the essential part of the image etc)., IrfanView is very handy. You can also process multiple images the same way (select the same area on each one, resize to 256x256 and save them all as *.raw).